# How can I make braket's \Set work with align* and htlatex/tex4ht

Tags: amsmath, align, tex4ht, htlatex

I have the following `test.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tex4ht}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \Set{|}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

When I run `latex`, I get

```
D:\Documents\GitHub\book> latex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\usepackage.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\braket\braket.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.4ht"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) ("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty"
--- needs --- tex4ht test ---
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.tmp)
l.1437 --- TeX4ht warning --- No file test.xref ---
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\fontmath.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\article.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\amsmath.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\amstext.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\amsbsy.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\amsopn.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
No file test.aux.
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.8 \end{align*}

?
```

What's going wrong, and how do I fix this?

**Edit**

Here is a smaller example with the same error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tex4ht}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \left\{{\egroup\;\middle|\;\bgroup}\right\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code `\begin{align*}\left\{\middle|\right\}\end{align*}` is sufficient to trigger the error, so it has nothing to do with `braket`.

Comment: if there's only one line, why use `align*`?  this doesn't fail with `\[ ... \]`.  and @egreg, your example doesn't fail if the expression is preceded by a `&`, although i haven't yet figured out why.